error A value of type 'int' cannot be used as a default parameter because there are no standard conversions to type
I have an error Error  CS1750  A value of type 'int' cannot be used as a default parameter because there are no standard conversions to type 'KtToast.Positions' and error   CS1750  A value of type 'int' cannot be used as a default parameter because there are no standard conversions to type 'KtToast.Hosts'
Please Guide me
How can I solve the error and I am also a beginner in C# or There was something wrong in the implementation of the code I created
Thanks
Below is the code I used :

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public sealed class KtToast : Component
    {
        public KtToast.SnackbarResult Show(Form owner, string message, KtToast.MessageTypes type = 0, int duration = 3000, string action = "", KtToast.Positions position = 1, KtToast.Hosts host = 2)
        {
        }
        public enum SnackbarResult
        {
            AutoClosed,
            UserClosed,
            ActionClicked
        }

        public enum Hosts
        {
            Screen,
            Control,
            FormOwner
        }
        public enum Positions
        {
            TopLeft,
            TopCenter,
            TopRight,
            MiddleLeft,
            MiddleCenter,
            MiddleRight,
            BottomLeft,
            BottomCenter,
            BottomRight,
            Custom
        }
        public enum MessageTypes
        {
            Information,
            Success,
            Warning,
            Error
        }
    }
}



Try setting it with Positions.TopCenter instead of 1 and see if it works then.

tl;dr enums are not ints

Enums are not int FYI Link
. For more detailed info use this link

See this Microsoft document, when we define  public enum Hosts { Screen, Control, FormOwner }, then we can use KtToast.Hosts host = KtToast.Hosts.Control) to set the variable.
Therefore, your class shall be
public KtToast.SnackbarResult Show(Form owner, string message, 
     KtToast.MessageTypes type = KtToast.MessageTypes.Information, 
     int duration = 3000, string action = "", 
     KtToast.Positions position = KtToast.Positions.TopCenter, 
     KtToast.Hosts host = KtToast.Hosts.FormOwner
)


Your answer helped me

Thank you for getting back with your test result here : )

you're welcome .  btw I have the latest post maybe you can help me link
